# Suddenly Getting Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java, tomcat, gradle, java-8

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/google/common/annotations/VisibleForTesting : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class com.google.common.annotations.VisibleForTesting)
```

Suddenly, without any change related to gradle or java jdk/jre version, i'm getting this run time error on my build server (ec2). I'm not getting it if I run it on my local computer.

I've made sure that java -version returns 1.7.0_x for both my build server and on my local computer. 
It was just fine for such a long time until today.

Comment: Maybe you have added a dependency compiled with Java 8 (probably guava or one of its dependencies).

Comment: It is possible the version of java in your build system is different. Could you print the environment variables as part of your build. If you are using maven, execute `mvn -v` to print the versions.

Comment: I havent added/removed any dependency, no change in my build.gradle file :x, build server also had no change. but I eventually tried installing java run time 1.8 on my build server and everything is good now... still, very strange

Comment: Unless you are building that google library from scratch, I would think that @pringi is right. Maybe the repository got updated

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue when re-building an unmodified application after returning from vacations. A library from the dependency tree now dependends on the latest version of the **Google Guava library**, which requires java 1.8.

From the exception you can read that `com/google/common/annotations/VisibleForTesting` causes your issue. The annotation type [VisibleForTesting](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/annotations/VisibleForTesting.html) is part of the Google Guava library. Since a few weeks [Guava Release 21.0](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ReleaseHistory) is available. From the [Release Notes](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/Release21) you can read...

> Important: Guava 21.0 requires Java 8.

You might not have changed your application's dependency tree, but for all that an indirect dependency to Guava 21.0 does exist. In my case it was the [com.googlecode.owasp-java-html-sanitizer](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.owasp-java-html-sanitizer/owasp-java-html-sanitizer/1.1) which depends on Guava 21.0. Downloading the JAR and looking into the dependency configuration (in my case maven) I saw that a Guava version >= 11.0 is required. This will be resolved to the latest version, thus 21. The dependency hierarchie view in my IDE came to the same conclusion.

Since you have upgraded your build server to JRE 1.8 in the meantime, the issue is gone (on your build server). Be aware: when you push your application into production your server will require JRE 1.8, too.